# Why do I get conda solving envioronment errors in every machine I work on?

Tags: python, conda

This is more of a general question on handling my conda environments. Everytime I try to install something with conda I always get stuck in a solving environment loop. I'll switch machines and start fresh and still get stuck in these loops. I'll try to install mamba instead and that doesn't help. Basically, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong everytime I install conda (its actually miniconda) which gives me the error. This happens on my local comps and the HPC servers I have access to. Is there a certian etiqutte of downloading conda and setting up environments that I am missing??
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "solving environment loop"? As in you're trying to download the modules that you need for you code?

Comment: yes, probably should've worried it better. Ever package I install turns into a "solving environment.... " and then will say fail and then trying to resolve it and it just keeps going on and on and this always happens to me. And I'll literally do a fresh conda install or even move machines and I still end up with the same issues. I feel like I am just doing something blatantly wrong

Comment: I think this is opinionated, but I'll share what I do: 1) install Mambaforge; 2) never use **base** environment for work; 3) create a new dedicated (minimal) environment for every project; 4) prefer using YAML or `conda-lock` files to define an environment - rarely use `mamba install`; 5) I also have generic "scratch" environments (e.g., `py11` or `r42` or `bioc_3_16`) where I will use `mamba install` to play with new packages, or write test scripts; but development and production all have dedicated minimal environments.